# How to realize the ERROR Path for Commands using MQTT-binding of the FIWARE IoT-Agent-JSON

Tags: mqtt, iot, fiware

from the FIWARE IoT-Agent-Json documentation I understand that there is the happy path and error path for command execution (https://fiware-iotagent-json.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usermanual.html#commands)

Using the MQTT-binding, sending a payload on the topic `/json/<APIKey>/<DeviceId>/cmdexe` always results in an update of the corresponding command-info to `OK`. This is fine as long the device does the right thing about receiving the command. However, how can I trigger an `ERROR`, e.g. the device receives the command, but can not execute it. Somehow with MQTT, I currently onyl understand the `_info` to be on either `PENDING` or `OK` once the IoT-Agent published the command to the device.

In which case will the `_info` udpated to `ERROR`? I could not find anything in the code about this scenario.

Thanks, for any help on this.